# git push doesn't update remote repository

Tags: git

We push commits to our git server and git server push changes to Github.

Our git server clone project like this: `git clone --bare git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git`, modify `post-update` script with: `git push --mirror &`, so after commits are pushed, these commits are also pushed to Github.

Deploy workflow:

- change to production branch
- merge `master` to production branch with `ff-only`
- push production branch to remote
- production servers pull production branch changes only

Sometimes we push commits to production branch successfully(git push returns successfully), but after we deployed, we found the commits are not pushed, we do these steps again, it works.

How to debug this issue?

---

### what I have done

- after pushing, I fetch remote and verify difference: `git fetch origin` and `git diff origin/production-branch`, it doesn't work.
- I have updated git server `git` from `1.9.1` to `2.14.2`, I don't know whether it works or not.

Comment: Perhaps you could redirect stdout and stderr to a logfile with `git push --mirror >& /tmp/gitmirror.log &`. Also I think your process is killed to early. Your post-update script should end with `wait`, which means you could also write `git push --mirror >& /tmp/gitmirror.log`.

Comment: `git push --mirror &` could be failed?@FabienBouleau

Comment: It could be that the background process is killed or an authentication issue. Only with a few more traces can you know. Also you can increase the ssh loglevel with `LogLevel DEBUG` in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file (put it after `Host github.com` or you will have debugging information for all your connections).

Comment: @FabienBouleau I redirect stdout and error to a file. Git push tracks background process state? I guess the push operation is successfully even push to github is failed, or my guess is wrong?